# animation of buttons in loop ios

Tags: ios, loops, animation, button

I have on view 81 buttons. What I want to do is that each button must go off the screen than when there are non, they must come back.

for example:

```
1.

***
***
***

2.
 **
***
***

3.
  *
***
***
```

and so one

than they must come back:

```
1.


  *

2.


 **

3.


***
```

and so one

I tried with [UIView animateWithDuration] in loop but it all animates together, not split:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i ++)
 for(int j = 0 ; j < 9 ; j ++){
  [uiview animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
   button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
  }
 }
```

Comment: it all animates together, not split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around a little

```
-(void)move1:(NSArray *)array index:(int)index {
UIButton *btn = array[index];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.frame.size.width, btn.frame.size.height);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if ([array count] != index+1) [self move1:array index:index+1];
}];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *buttonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:b1,b2,b3,b4,b5, nil];

    [self move1:buttonArray index:0];
}
```

Comment: This should be the thing ur looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to move every button at once. Add every UIButton in a UIView, then move that UIView offscreen.

Otherwise add every button in a NSArray and use a for loop to move them all like this:

```
for (UIButton *btn in buttonArray) {
    btn.frame = [CGRectMake(width, height, x, y)];
}
```

Comment: no u miss understand me. i want to animate every button individual

Comment: Thats what the for loop does

Comment: I know that and i tried it like that, but animation pull's all my buttons at once. Like i wrote it in upper code

Answer (score -1):

```
      AddEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);// function to show the bottons back again
    function update(e:Event){
    //manipulate te propety to move sidewards
    x = x - speed; // move to the left
    // aceleration
    speed = speed + 0,1;
    // limit the positino to stay on the screen
    if (x < -width) { // meanes off the left of the screen
    X = stage.stageWidth + width;
    }}
```

> Add the code above inside of movieClip or the botton. the below to the scene.

```
      AddEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainloop);

        function mainloop(e:Event){
        for (var i = 0; i<nunChildren; i++){
        }
```

Comment: With this code you are able to animate individualy any botton. Intrested in random the position?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIgyHAmfJIM <- this will help you solve your problem.